# How I solve $-2x + 7y + 6 = 20$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I've been having trouble trying to figure out this linear equation. I only know how to calculate with two variables and no constant, I'm not good at figuring out problems with new "formats" if that's the right word.

I tried subtracting $6$ from both sides, but I don't think that's the right way to do it. I think I'm supposed to subtract $7y$ from both sides? Could you help me learn how to graph and solve this equation?

Comment: Subtracting $6$ from each side is a good start.  That gives you the equation of a line in standard form.  If you prefer slope-intercept form, isolate $y$.

Comment: Oh! So I was on the right track! Thank you so much!

Comment: To isolate $y$, you would be better off adding $2x$ to both sides after you subtract $6$ from each side.

Comment: It would be good to know what you mean by "solve". For example the equation $x+y=1$ has the solutions $(1,0), (0,1), (2,-1), (-1,2),\dots$ See where this is heading?

Comment: Forgive me if I wasn't clear, what I mean by solve is to either simplify the equation in slope intercept form or standard to graph the points in a Cartesian Plane.

Comment: In a linear equation having more variables (you have two $x$ and $y$) than equations (you have exactly one equation: $-2x + 7y +6 = 20$) will have an infinite number of solutions.  A solution is a pair of values $(s_1,s_2)$ where $x=s_1; y=s_2$.  There are an infinite number of them.  $x=0;y=2$ is one $x=-7;y=0$ is another.  $x=7;y=4$ is a third and so on.....

Comment: To get $-2x +7y + 6 = 20$ to $y = mx + b$ form is just to "unwrap" the $y$.  You already have the $7y$ on the left hand so so move everything else to the right.  Subtract $6$ to both side: $-2x+7y = 14$ .  Add $2x$ to both sides $7y = 2x + 14$.  Or do those in the opposite order; it doesn't matter: $-2x+7y+6=20$, add $2x$: $7y+6=2x+20$, subtract $6$; $7y = 2x + 14$.  Now to unwrap the $y$, divide by $7$.  $y =\frac {2x+14}7 = \frac 27x + 2$.... Note you can be a masochist and do it in any order.  Dive by $7$ first? Sure: $-\frac 27x + y + \frac 67 = \frac {20}7$ ... you'll get the same answer.

Comment: @fleablood thank you!

Comment: Question: When I add $2x$ to both sides, why is it to other side? Is it because we're just rearranging like you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common way to graph a function like this is to write it in what is known as slope-intercept form. Slope-intercept form is of the form

$$y=mx+b,$$

where $m$ is the slope, and $b$ is the $y$-intercept. For your problem, we need to solve for $y$:

\begin{align*}
-2x+7y+6&=20\\
-2x+7y&=14&\text{by subtracting $6$ to both sides}\\
7y&=2x+14&\text{by adding $2x$ to both sides}\\
y&=\frac27x+2&\text{by dividing by $7$ on both sides}
\end{align*}

This is an equation of a line in slope-intercept form. The slope is $2/7$ and the $y$-intercept is $2$.

To graph it, first plot the $y$-intercept, which is $(0,2)$. To find the next point on our line, we use the slope. You may have heard of "slope is rise over run". In our case, the slope is $2/7$, so our "rise" is $2$, and our "run" is $7$. That is, starting from $(0,2)$, we go up by $2$, and go to the right by $7$, giving us a second point of $(7,4)$. Connecting $(0,2)$ and $(7,4)$ gives us our line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna try to challenge myself and try standard form and slope intercept form.

Answer (score 1):

By subtracting 6 from both sides you will get:
-2x + 7y = 14.

To plot this equation on the graph, assume any value of one of the variables and find the other.

Assume x=0, then you will get 7y = 14. Therefore y = 2.
So, First point becomes (0, 2).

Similarly assume y=0, then you will get -2x=14. Therefore x=-7.
So second point becomes (-7, 0)

Connect these two points on the x-y plane.

You can choose and other value of x or y, you will get the resultant point on the graph of your equation.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).